# CBCentralManager changes for iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, ios7, core-bluetooth

I am trying to use Apple's '[BTLE Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html)' sample project to understand CoreBluetooth programming. The app runs fine if I use an iOS 6 device as the Central, but if I run the same app with the iOS 7 device as the Central it doesn't work. The peripheral stops sending after two packets, and the central doesn't receive either one of them.

The only clue is this warning that I get only when running on iOS 7:

```
CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBCentralManager: 0x15654540> is disabling duplicate filtering, but is using the default queue (main thread) for delegate events
```

Can anyone tell me what needs to change to make this app compatible with iOS 7?

EDIT: When *both* devices are iOS7 there are no issues. This only breaks when an iOS7 central is talking to a iOS6 peripheral.

Answer (score 8):

Okay I just ran it on an iOS 7 central to iOS 6 peripheral. If you want to make that warning about disabling duplicate filtering go away, just run it on a different thread. Do something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yo.mycentral", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);// or however you want to create your dispatch_queue_t
_centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:centralQueue];
```

Now it will allow you to scan with duplicates enabled. However, you must call the textView setter on the main thread to be able to set the text without crashing:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.textview setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        });
```

Btw you probably also want to adopt the new iOS 7 delegate initialization:

```
_centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:centralQueue options:nil];//set the restoration options if you want
```

(Just check the iOS version and call the appropriate initialization method)

Comment: That does eliminate the warning, but it does not fix the communication issue. It is apparently a known issue when communicating between iOS 6 and 7.

Answer (score 5):

In`scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:`,if you set `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@YES` then change it to
`CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@NO`that means scan should run without duplicate filtering.

For me,it works on iOS7 also.